# Google Foobar : logical error in a sub optimal solution

Tags: python, algorithm, logic

**Question**

Write a function answer(l) that takes a list of positive integers l and counts the number of "lucky triples" of (lst[i], lst[j], lst[k]) where i < j < k. The length of l is between 2 and 2000 inclusive. The elements of l are between 1 and 999999 inclusive. The answer fits within a signed 32-bit integer. Some of the lists are purposely generated without any access codes to throw off spies, so if no triples are found, return 0.

Lucky Triples are basically tuples (x,y,z) where x divides y and y divides z. e.g (1,2,4).

For example, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] has the triples: [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 6], [1, 3, 6], making the answer 3 total.

**My Code**

```
def isLuckyTriple(a,b,c):
    if b%a==0 and c%b==0:
        return True
    return False
def solution(l):
    count=0
    l=sorted(l)
    for i in range(len(l)-2):
        for j in range(i+1,len(l)-1):
            for k in range(j+1,len(l)):
                if isLuckyTriple(l[i],l[j],l[k]):
                    count+=1
    return count
```

**My problem**

I have viewed a few stackoverflow answers regarding this question. I know how to do it in a different and more optimal way. The only problem is that my above code passes only 2 test cases out of 5 given test cases. I want to understand what I am doing wrong in the **above code**. I am more interested in figuring my mistake out instead of doing it in a better way.

If you do not think the code is incorrect, then could it be failing the test cases because the solution is very slow?

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `l=sorted(l)` step because it changes the order of indices of numbers since one of the constraints say `i < j < k`.

Consider below case:

`4 2 1`

Answer should be `0` but your code will return `1`.

---

Regarding efficiency, you can count how many numbers each number divides from the right. For `1,2,3,4,5,6` the counts for each would look like:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
5 2 1 0 0 0
```

For `1`, when you come to `2`, `2` already has `2` in the cached array, so now you got 2 triplets to add to the final answer. You get `1` triplet when you come to `3`, So `2+1` = `3`.

**Time Complexity:** O(n^2)

**Space Complexity:** O(n)

---

Since, the question says `The elements of l are between 1 and 999999 inclusive`, I think you can just go the factorial way.

First collect all value counts in a map.

Now, go every multiple for every number and add the triplets from last to first. Like below:

```
triplet_map = {}
map = {}
for every number in array: # from last to first
   if number in triplet_map:
       triplets += triplet_map(number)
       continue
   cnt = 0
   for(i = number; i < 1000000; i *= number) 
     if i in map:
         if map(i) > 0: 
           cnt += map(i)
     map(number,map(number) + 1)
   triplets += cnt
   triplet_map(number,cnt)
```

This way, it's like logarithmic time for each number. Didn't test this much but seems to work.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. I tried verifying my solution with sorted(l) and without it, it still passes 2 test cases only. Can you see any other error in the above code? And yes, the last code you did is way wayy better.

Comment: @MuhammadAnasBhatti  Without `sorted(l)`, it should work. You can try for the suggested O(n^2) solution. Maybe FooBar doesn't report time limited exceeded issues and just reports for a pass or fail.

Comment: I think you're right. Execution time must be limited. Besides your solution, I have thought of another solution where i find dividers of every element from its left and multiples of every element from its right and multiply the count of both. This gives me number of possible tuples for one single element. I add that to my TotalCount variable. Do you think it would work?

Comment: @VeryBhatti That should work too. Just count the duplicates from left and right as well since we are looking for indices i,j,k.

Answer (score 1):

```
def answer(l):
    triples_count=0

    p=len(l)
    print l
    for i in xrange(p-2):
        for j in xrange(i+1, p-1):
            if l[j] % l[i] == 0:
                for k in xrange(j+1, p):
                    if l[k] % l[j] == 0:
                        #print l[i], l[j], l[k]
                        triples_count=triples_count+1
    return(triples_count)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a time limit for each question, I think it is about 15 seconds. As far as I have noticed, all test cases run in parallel when you verify and the test case will fail if you exceed 15 seconds. having O(n^3) time complexity will definitely fail the test cases.